# Combine audio and video with avconv not merging video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, libav

I am trying to combine a ripped stream from YouTube that seems to be in a weird format.  Anyway, the video and audio seem to play on their own but when I tried to combine it, the file size is just a little bit bigger than the audio file's original size so it seems to have done nothing.

```
jonathan@localhost:~/foo$ avconv -i video.mp4 -i audio.m4a -c copy audio_and_video.mp4
avconv version 0.8.16-6:0.8.16-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Sep 16 2014 23:10:48 with gcc 4.7.2
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2014-12-06 03:30:37
  Duration: 00:31:35.36, start: 947.680067, bitrate: 1939 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 tbr, 90k     tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-12-06 03:30:37
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'audio.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6mp41
    creation_time   : 2014-12-13 10:25:20
  Duration: 00:31:35.42, start: 947.745193, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #1.0(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-12-13 10:25:20
Output #0, mov, to 'audio_and_video.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2014-12-06 03:30:37
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-12-06 03:30:37
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-12-13 10:25:20
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   14892kB time=947.68 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s
video:0kB audio:14530kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.493168%
```

And some additional info:

```
jonathan@localhost:~/foobar$ file audio.m4a
audio.m4a: ISO Media
jonathan@localhost:~/foobar$ file video.mp4
video.mp4: ISO Media
jonathan@localhost:~/foobar$ file audio_and_video.mp4
audio_and_video.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 1
jonathan@localhost:~/foobar$ ls -lh
total 468M
-rw-r--r-- 1 jonathan jonathan  15M Mar 12 12:29 audio_and_video.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 jonathan jonathan  15M Dec 14 23:50 audio.m4a
-rw-r--r-- 1 jonathan jonathan 439M Dec 14 23:50 video.mp4
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how it can be fixed is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This avconv is already a little old. Can you try a more recent build or alternatively a static ffmpeg build from ffmpeg.org?

Comment: Hmm, I think you are right.  I downloaded and compiled it, and installed it.  It now successfully combined the audio and video stream.  What is weird, when I run `avconv` by itself, it uses the old version.  When I say `which avconv` it points to `/usr/local/bin` and it shows todays version that I just compiled.  So.. kinda weird, that.

Comment: Hmm, make sure you reset your shell or ran `hash -r` (in Bash) or `rehash` in Zsh.

Comment: I am using bash but hasn isn't a command it recognises.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, typo. I meant `hash -r`. (edited)

Comment: Oh man, I ran it as root and when I exited back to myself I assumed it would had worked, then when I reran it, I made a typo as my normal account (but was a valid command so it didn't recognise the -r switch)... okay, I am good now, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since avconv 0.8.6 is a bit old, this seems like a bug which can be resolved by installing a recent version of either avconv (or ffmpeg, as you indicated in the tags of your question).

Note that these two are [different projects but *very* similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/435093) in terms of syntax and functionality, and getting a recent version is as simple as downloading a "static build" from [ffmpeg.org](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), which exist for all major operating systems. No compilation needed—extract and run.

For avconv, only Windows builds exist, so there you'd have to compile it yourself.

In general, with avconv and ffmpeg you generally want to use a recent version rather than what the standard distributions offer in their package sources.

Comment: I am using Linux (Debian) with bash as my shell.  After wget, configure, make, make install and git make install it worked `avconv` as root, but as a regular user I had to give it the full path, even though according to `which` was pointing to /usr/local/share/bin.